# Tell whether a text string is an IPv6 address or IPv4 address using standard C sockets API

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have a program where an external component passes me a string which contains an IP address. I then need to turn it into a URI. For IPv4 this is easy; I prepend http:// and append /. However, for IPv6 I need to also surround it in brackets [].

Is there a standard sockets API call to determine the address family of the address?

Comment: I know that it's not part of the sockets API, but if IP4 and IP6 are the only possibilities, can't you do this with `strlen`? ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop consider e.g. ff02::2 and 8.8.8.8

Comment: @nos: fair enough, didn't realise the former was a valid address. More generally, is there some way to examine the strings, that's simpler code than using the sockets API? In this case, the structure containing the parsed address isn't needed.

Comment: If you know that this string is either an ipv4 or ipv6 address, looking for . or : might be enough. Parsing an ipv4 address is rather trivial depending on the level of validation you need, an ipv6 address is quite a bit worse.

Comment: Considered this; decided it would be too hacky and might not extend if we want to support something other than IPv4 and IPv6 (not very likely, but in my experience I would greatly increase its likelihood by writing code that doesn't support it).

Comment: @nos: I guess finding a colon (:) could mean that it is ipv6, but looking for a dot (.) would not help, as I understand that there are "mixed mode" ipv6 addresses which contain dots.  But then again, an ipv4 address could have :port.  I guess an ipv6 address would have to contain at least 2 colons?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [getaddrinfo](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getaddrinfo.html)() and set the hint flag AI_NUMERICHOST, family to AF_UNSPEC, upon successfull return from getaddrinfo, the resulting struct addrinfo .ai_family member will be either AF_INET or AF_INET6.

EDIT, small example

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hint, *res = NULL;
    int ret;

    memset(&hint, '\0', sizeof hint);

    hint.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hint.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;

    ret = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hint, &res);
    if (ret) {
        puts("Invalid address");
        puts(gai_strerror(ret));
        return 1;
    }
    if(res->ai_family == AF_INET) {
        printf("%s is an ipv4 address\n",argv[1]);
    } else if (res->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
        printf("%s is an ipv6 address\n",argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("%s is an is unknown address format %d\n",argv[1],res->ai_family);
    }

   freeaddrinfo(res);
   return 0;
}

$ ./a.out 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 is an ipv4 address
$ ./a.out ff01::01
ff01::01 is an ipv6 address
```

Answer (score 30):

Kind of.  You could use `inet_pton()` to try parsing the string first as an IPv4 (`AF_INET`) then IPv6 (`AF_INET6`).  The return code will let you know if the function succeeded, and the string thus contains an address of the attempted type.

For example:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int
ip_version(const char *src) {
    char buf[16];
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, src, buf)) {
        return 4;
    } else if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, src, buf)) {
        return 6;
    }
    return -1;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s\t%d\n", argv[i], ip_version(argv[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: getaddrinfo() has bunch of overhead but basically also calls inet_pton(). inet_pton() is really all you need and IMHO the best answer to this question. It also doesn't require a cleanup function.

Comment: the 'else' is redundant since the first if directly returns. Will be flagged by some linters.

Comment: also should be inet_pton > 0 since this function returns -1 in error cases