# How to know IP version by the IP address

Tags: objective-c

How can I know what is my `IP version` (4 or 6) by my IP address or else other way?

I want to find it by programming.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the most trivial way to do it would be to check for a ':' character within the address.

Comment: What format?  String format or raw as passed to `bind(2)`?

Answer (score 0):

A question very similar to this one, if not identical, has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736335/tell-whether-a-text-string-is-an-ipv6-address-or-ipv4-address-using-standard-c-s)

Since you tagged your question with `Objective-C,` you can write C code within your code without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I appreciate your time @shaik :)